# Elastic Search Query for displaying the documents when it contains all the set of specific properties

Tags: api, elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search APIs. I have a requirement where i need to query and list the documents which compulsorily contains following properties, say

"request: "/v3?id=100000" & "type: "GET"

Result should contains list of documents containing both the above. I have tried the following and it gets either of the above.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
               "type": "GET"
           }
    }
}
```

I tried

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
               "type": "GET",
               "request: "/v3/id=100000"
           }
    }
}
```

It fails...

Can someone suggest me a query to list all the docs with both the properties set as above ? Not sure how to use filters, if I try it shows failures - parse exceptions.

My example document:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.04.22",
  "_type": "endpoint-access",
  "_id": "fAhTQkDRQTiHKlzuleNA",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-04-22T15:26:35.153Z",
    "offset": "43714176",
    "ident": "-",
    "auth": "-",
    "timestamp": "22/Apr/2016:15:26:35 +0000",
    "type": "GET",
    "request": "/v3?id=1b32e833-b521",
    "httpversion": "1.1",
    "response": "500",
    "bytes": "265",
    "referrer": "-",
    "agent": "-",
    "x_forwarded_for": "\"101.2.123.24\""
    "host": "101.123.115.167"
  },
  "sort": [
    1461338795153,
    1461338795153
  ]
}
```

Comment: You want to get those records whose `id=100000`???

Comment: Can you post example of your documents?

Comment: added the example document. 
Requirement is to get all the document 

which has type = GET and "request": "/v3?id=1b32e833-b521"

Comment: Please specify the mapping too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use "must" to get the result:

```
{

 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "match": {
           "type": "GET"
         }
       },
       {
         "match": {
           "request": "/v3/id=100000"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 } 
}
```